# Excel/Google Sheets pivot function VS python pivot function

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-sheets, pivot-table

I am trying to pivot a dataframe in python. I used the **[pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)** function in python. The trouble is that when I tried to verify the result with the pivot table created in Google Sheets, **both the results were different**. Also the **number of rows after pivoting is different in both the cases**. I am confused now as to what is going on here! Why are the results of a same function different? Aren't they supposed to do the same thing??!

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yd5DE8pOwDxzolRdySTkZUkjsQdEfjB1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102761340950551340910&rtpof=true&sd=true) is the link to the data and the pivot table done in Google Sheets. The `Order item ID 2` should be the **index** as it is the unique ID and the `Settlement Value` should be the **values** where it should be aggregated.

Below is the code I use to create pivot table in python with the same data:

```
payout = pd.read_excel('combined aug-dec payout.xlsx')
payout['Order item ID'] = payout['Order item ID'].apply(str)
payout['Order item ID 2'] = 'OI:' + payout['Order item ID']
pivot_settle = payout.pivot_table(index = ['Order item ID 2'], values = ['Settlement Value'], aggfunc = 'sum')
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 1. Post a URL to the pivot table in google spreadsheets. 2. Post your code of making a pivot table with pandas.

Comment: The URL to the pivot table and the data is present in the link I have provided. Also posted the code I used to create pivot table.

Comment: I checked them. And both of them have 17,754 rows. I didn't find any problems here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that `Order item ID 2` contains Google Sheet formulas, not raw data, that are not parsed by Pandas as intended: OI:121314525072009**01** becomes OI:121314525072009**00** when the Excel file is imported. And thus, when you aggregate on this column, you end up whith less rows than in Google Sheet pivot table.

So, first, copy/paste values to overwrite formulas in this column, save the file, and then, pivoting your data with Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("combined aug-dec payout.xlsx")

print(
    pd.pivot_table(
        df,
        index="Order item ID 2",
        values="Settlement Value",
        aggfunc=sum,
    ).shape[0]
)
# Ouput: 17,754 rows
```

And with Google Sheets: `17,754 rows`.

Comment: But I am not importing this file. What I am doing is creating the new column `Order item ID 2` in python itself and then pivoting it.

Comment: I have edited my question for more details!